# Is there a way to decompress the .dl_ and .sy_ files included on pre-WIM/ESD installation media of Windows from Linux?

Tags: linux, compression, cab, windows-nt-4

Before Windows took on the image-based approach with `.wim` and `.esd` files (Windows 7 and newer?!), the installation media -- for example for Windows NT 4 -- included files like `shell32.dl_` and `win32k.sy_`.

From Windows itself you would use the built-in tool `expand` ("LZ Expansion Utility" or
"File Expansion Utility") to decompress these files. Otherwise, obviously, the setup routine itself would do that, with the description inside `txtsetup.sif` in `[SourceDisksFiles]`.

Is there a way to achieve the same on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

The [`cabextract(1)` utility](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cabextract) available in many Linux distributions is able to decompress these files.

As it turns out these files are proper cabinet (`.cab`) files with just a single file each:

```
$ file win32k.sy_
win32k.sy_: Microsoft Cabinet archive data, Windows 2000/XP setup, 745326 bytes, 1 file, at 0x2c "win32k.sys", number 1, 39 datablocks, 0x1 compression
```